# Why doesn't this DAO recordset query return any results?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am working on an Access 2007 database and I have set up a DAO recordset query, however, it is not returning any results. It does not throw up any errors, just no results. Me.ProID is a text field, it includes letters and numbers. I think it has something to do with the text field, maybe the placement of quotations.

```
Dim contractSQL As String
Dim contractDB As DAO.Database
Dim contractRS As DAO.Recordset

contractSQL = "SELECT Top 1 ContractName, ItemDescription, Price FROM ContractPricing WHERE AccountNo = " & Me.Parent.[AccntNumber] & " AND PartNo = " & """ & Me.ProdID & """ & " ORDER BY Price Asc"

Set contractDB = CurrentDb
Set contractRS = contractDB.OpenRecordset(contractSQL)

Debug.Print contractRS.RecordCount
```

Comment: The `contractSQL = "SELECT ...` line triggers a compile error due to this -> `& """ &`  That is present in 2 places in that line.  Do you want this instead? -> `& "'" &`  Or this? -> `& """" &`

Comment: On way to track this down would be to set a breakpoint on your assignment for contractSQL, perform the assignment (i.e. do one step) and then print the assigned SQL statement in the debug window. Then copy & paste it to a query and see what happens and what needs to be changed.

Comment: HansUp, thanks for the solution you had it right on. Alexander Remesch, thanks for the tip on future troubleshooting. That is really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string concatenation is likely wrong. `" & """ & Me.ProdID & """ & "` should almost certainly be `'" & Me.ProdID & "'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're referring to this:

```
contractSQL = "SELECT Top 1 ContractName, ItemDescription, Price FROM ContractPricing WHERE AccountNo = " & Me.Parent.[AccntNumber] & " AND PartNo = " & Me.ProdID & " ORDER BY Price Asc"
```

I'm not sure if this would help you. I'm also new to this. But hopefully it will.